# Nodemailer: My frontend website can't send emails through node mailer from a different IP address

Tags: node.js, express, backend, nodemailer

My frontend portfolio has an emailing option which sends a post req to nodemailer in the backend.
My portfolio is already deployed in firebase and I'm currently running the backend on the localhost server.

I face no issues when I send emails on my laptop, same IP address, while I receive an error whenever I try sending emails on a different device.

I have searched around for a day now and I can't find an available solution. Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

My nodemailer configuration:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    name: 'domainname',
    host: 'domainname.com',
    port: 443,
    secure: true,
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: '*****@gmail.com',
        pass: '******' //Google's less secure apps option enabled.
    },
    tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }
}))
```

The following error is logged into the console when sending email fails:

```
POST http://localhost:4000/api/email/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at main.1ec56b92.js:2:347746
    at c (main.1ec56b92.js:2:168378)
    at Generator._invoke (main.1ec56b92.js:2:168166)
    at Generator.next (main.1ec56b92.js:2:168807)
    at Ft (main.1ec56b92.js:2:332714)
    at i (main.1ec56b92.js:2:347506)
    at main.1ec56b92.js:2:347567
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at main.1ec56b92.js:2:347446
    at main.1ec56b92.js:2:348157
```

Thank you

Comment: Any errors on frontend or backend?

Comment: I receive a typical error that the email failed to be sent on the frontend, something I manually added, but amazingly enough I receive no error on the backend.

Comment: If there is no error on the backend, how do you know sending the email failed on the frontend? On what do you pin this "manually added" error?

Comment: Besides not receiving the email, I also catch an error on my fetch req which then displays an error on the UI.

Comment: And it didn't come to your mind that the fetch err you are catching might be of any interest? So what's the fetch error you are catching? (Status code, response body, console output)

Comment: I did, but since I only use the website on my phone I can' see the displayed error on the console.

Comment: Well then how is anybody supposed to be able to help without knowing anything about the error? Have you tried connecting your mobile to your laptop and do remote debugging? Or not just displaying some generic error message on your website but the exact error you caught?

Comment: I didn't think about it, I'll try that and hopefully update you with the available, readable, error.

Comment: I'm back, first thank you for suggesting remote debugging, I used chrome's remote inspection which is easy and will come in handy in the future. I have updated my post to include the error this time.

Comment: Well the error says it all, doesn't it? You have the host of your backend hardcoded as `localhost:4000` which is, why it works on your local machine. But when running it on your phone, `localhost` doesn't point to your laptop but (as the name suggests) your local device, ie the phone. Obviously there is no server running there. You have to use the IP address or network name of your laptop here.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation . I'm solving the issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

As Derpirscher pointed out, the host of the backend was hardcoded as localhost:4000 hence why it worked on my laptop and failed on my phone.
The solution for me was to deploy the code to a server -like Heroku- and use its address to connect to the nodemailer API, eg: https://project.herokuapp.com/api/email instead of https://localhost:4000/api/email

Comment: Well hopefully you added some sort of authorization to your service as otherwise you created a nice spam relay ...

Comment: I didn't add any authorization to the backend..

Comment: Well you should, because otherwise anybody can just post to your app and send emails in your name ...

Comment: Oh I see, luckily the website is a portfolio to land an internship, hence why everyone is welcome to send emails, which will be received in my inbox. Also, thank you Derpischer for your suggestions, I appreciate your help.